# Right Alt selects text on the right instead of entering an alternative character

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 13.10, google-chrome, keyboard-layout

My keyboard works just fine in editors like vim or LibreOffice, but I can't make it work in Google Chrome.

Whenever I type something in a form on certain web pages like the search bar on Facebook, or jakdojade.pl and I want to use special characters (I'm Polish, so I use them quite a lot), after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> the whole form gets selected and when I press the key I wanted to insert it deletes the whole text leaving me with the letter I just inserted only. I tried changing settings of my keyboard but it didn't work.

The only workaround I found so far is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and while holding it press <kbd>►</kbd> and than the letter (for the input to get unselected and not deleted).

Do you guys have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This is a bug that still exists in 16.04! Please report it on Launchpad to give it higher priority: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1484157

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to **System Settings**.
2. Select **Keyboard**.
3. On the Keyboard window select the **Shortcuts** tab.
4. In the left panel select Typing (pol. Pisanie) and set a *Key for typing alternative characters* (pol. Klawisz wprowadzania alternatywnych znaków).

Comment: I have it set already. Today I found, that the problem only exists on some webpages like: search bar on Facebook, or jakdojade.pl. The alternative characters enter perfectly on Google etc.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use alternative characters after upgrading Ubuntu to 13.10.
What fixed it was setting my compose key from being disabled to being set to a key (I chose <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, which I never use).
You can do so in **Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing > Compose Key**.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, mind you, this is also happening on a Windows 10 machine (spring update) with a chrome browser (66):

We're making a drupal site with CKEDITOR as wysiwyg.
He reported a bug, that in **some** articles he was trying to write, the Polish "ą" character would select all text.
After some debugging, i found that this would only happen if the text area begins or ends with

1. a numbered list

or

- a bulleted list

It had to be rendered by ckeditor. If you switched to HTML, there is no selecting of text.

This only happens inside Chrome, if you have the Polish keyboard installed, and only with the polish letter ą (right <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Not even sure where the bug is, some library? Chrome?